# List of uses of For Loops

Tags: oop

Can someone please list the possible uses of For loops in programming in general?

I would like to know so that when I have an issue, I can say "aha" a For loop would be perfect for that.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: simple search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/for_loops.html) for informations about the for-loop.